# My computer uses an ARM-based CPU. How can I run the Android emulator with optimal performance?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, arm, qemu

My Ubuntu runs on the Atom (ARM-based) CPU. How  can I run the Android emulator with optimal performance?

First off, here is some more information about my OS and CPU:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux mypc 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
 1  processor   : 0
 2  vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
 3  cpu family  : 6
 4  model       : 77
 5  model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  C2550  @ 2.40GHz
 6  stepping    : 8
 7  microcode   : 0x122
 8  cpu MHz     : 2400.097
 9  cache size  : 1024 KB
10  physical id : 0
11  siblings    : 4
12  core id     : 0
13  cpu cores   : 4
14  apicid      : 0
15  initial apicid  : 0
16  fpu     : yes
17  fpu_exception   : yes
18  cpuid level : 11
19  wp      : yes
20  flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
21  bugs        :
22  bogomips    : 4800.19
23  clflush size    : 64
24  cache_alignment : 64
25  address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
26  power management:
```

I have installed Android Studio and use its emulator to run x86-based system images without problems.

But I heard that I can gain some performance boost if I run the emulator the ARM-based qemu. I am not sure if this is true. And I don't even know how to do it.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: "Atom (ARM-based) CPU" - not sure where you got this impression, as Atom CPUs are x86/x86_64 CPUs, rather than ARM-based. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom)

Comment: @bouteillebleu Thanks for your comment. I think you are right. I recently created a machine on packet.net and I wrongly thought the CPU must be ARM-based because of this: https://www.packet.net/bare-metal/servers/type-2a/  Like you said, my presumption was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @bouteillebleu, my presumption in the question was wrong.

I am marking this question as closed.